# Fraction in Superscript

Tags: superscripts, fractions

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
\newcommand\sufr[2]{\textsuperscript{$\frac{#1}{#2}$}}
  \begin{document}
text\sufr{1}{6}  

राम\sufr{1}{6}
  \end{document}
```

In the above example, I managed to get fraction in superscript. However did not like the place where the fraction appears. It can be seen in the Devanagari text that the output does not appear like a superscript.

How can I raise the fraction number. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a modified version of `\sufr` that now takes an optional argument indicating the raise quantity:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand\sufr[3][0pt]{$\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr#1+1.4ex\relax}^\frac{#2}{#3}$}
\begin{document}
text$^\frac{1}{6}$ \quad text\sufr{1}{6} \quad text\sufr[5pt]{1}{6} 
\end{document}
​
```

The example sets the regular sans-`\sufr`-style superscript fraction, followed by the regular `\sufr`, followed by a `5pt` raise of the fraction. The default raise is `0pt`, which is similar to a regular superscript fraction.

Take caution of possible line height imperfections with such use, as is shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand\sufr[3][0pt]{$\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr#1+1.4ex\relax}^\frac{#2}{#3}$}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr[5pt]{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy\sufr{1}{6} dog.
\end{document}
```

You could, of course, `\smash` the superscript, but that may cause overlay problems.

Comment: Oh, how I wish the math `\fontdimen`s worked with XeTeX `;-)`

Comment: awesome!!! thanks for offering me the flexibility by making the raise variable.